# Transformação de imagem de acordo com parâmetros de uma foto

Tags: python, opencv

Eu tenho uma foto aérea de um lago e tenho um arquivo .geojson com um polígono que representa o contorno desse lago num mapa real.

Estou fazendo a conversão de latitude, longitude e altitude para X, Y, Z usando o seguinte código:

```
lonDiff = lonMax - lonMin
latDiff = latMax - latMin
altDiff = altMax - altMin

if (lonDiff > latDiff and lonDiff > altDiff):
    distMax = lonDiff
if (latDiff > lonDiff and latDiff > altDiff):
    distMax = latDiff
if (altDiff > lonDiff and altDiff > latDiff):
    distMax = altDiff

adjustment = imgSize/distMax

vectors = []
vetores = np.zeros((len(coordList),3))

vectorsX = []
vectorsY = []
vectorsZ = []

for i in range(0,len(coordinates)):
    vectors[i][0] = (coordinates[i][0] - lonMin) * adjustment
    vectors[i][1] = (coordinates[i][1] - latMin) * adjustment
    vectors[i][2] = (coordinates[i][2] - altMin) * adjustment
    
    vectorsX.append((coordinates[i][0] - lonMin) * adjustment)
    vectorsY.append((coordinates[i][1] - latMin) * adjustment)
    vectorsZ.append((coordinates[i][2] - altMin) * adjustment)
```

O que eu preciso é plotar esses valores (X,Y,Z) na tela, porém com uma distorção baseada nos parâmetros de angulação do momento em que a foto foi tirada para que o contorno se alinhe perfeitamente ao lago. Tenho um arquivo txt com os parâmetros (como X_pos, Y_pos, Altitude, Yaw, Pitch, Roll, etc) de 16 fotografias diferentes desse lago.

Segue um exemplo simples do que preciso (feito no Paint):

[image: A plotagem original, baseada nas coordenadas de lat, long e altitude]

[image: A projeção sobre o lago (a saída do programa)]

Já tentei utilizar as transformações afins do pacote OpenCV, que parece ser a melhor opção aqui, mas não consegui implementar pois preciso do input de pontos específicos para serem usados como referência e não consigo fazer isso pois as coordenadas vão mudar para cada arquivo geojson que for inserido no programa.

Não sei mais o que posso tentar além disso. Não me parece ser algo muito complexo em termos de código, basta aplicar os parâmetros no contorno visto de cima, mas a matemática/transformação da imagem não está clara na minha cabeça, e não tenho certeza se realmente preciso do OpenCV pra isso.

Qualquer resposta ou ajuda será muito bem recebida, e se algo não ficou suficientemente claro, por favor, me diga para que eu explique melhor e possamos encontrar alguma solução.

Answer (score 1):

Como foi informado, tu já tem os pontos do polígono em relação ao sistema de referências
[image]
(vamos chamar os pontos de
[image]),
bem como os parâmetros do ponto de observação
[image].
Uma nova variável a ser adicionada é o centro do ponto de observação do Polígono [image].

A diferença de
[image]
e
[image]
lhe informará a distância entre o ponto central do mapa e o ponto de observação da fotografia. Essa distância em álgebra linear, no que diz respeito a Matrizes de Transformação, se chama Translação
[image]. A relação entre os pontos
[image]
e
[image]
lhe fornece também os ângulos de onde a foto foi tirada, vamos chamar esse ângulo aqui de matriz de rotação denominada por
[image].
O conjunto de operações de rotação e translação representa uma matriz de transformação
[image],
conforme definida abaixo:

[image]

A figura abaixo demonstra gráficamente as operações de uma [Matriz de Transformação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_de_transforma%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para um sistema de referências X,Y.

[image]

Desta forma, tu consegue aplicar uma transformação homogênea nos pontos do polígono com a finalidade de "alinhar" a mesma perspectiva da foto aplicando a seguinte operação:

[image]

A composição das matrizes de rotação tu pode encontrar aqui [Matriz de Rotação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_de_rota%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Como não tenho os dados originais, vou fazer uma demonstração de um conjunto de pontos que formam o polígono de um losango. A rotação será de 45° apenas em um ângulo (gamma), no entanto, pode ser usada a rotação nos demais ângulos, conforme é mostrado em [Matriz de Transformação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_de_transforma%C3%A7%C3%A3o). A translação ocorrerá em 0.4 para x e 0.6 para y, ou seja, os pontos serão deslocados em x e y, conforme os valores informados.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def H(R_gamma, T, angle = 'rad'):
    if angle == 'deg':
        R_gamma = np.deg2rad(R_gamma)
    th_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(R_gamma),   -np.sin(R_gamma), 0.,      T[0]],
                          [np.sin(R_gamma),   np.cos(R_gamma),  0.,      T[1]],
                          [0.,          0.,                     1.,      T[2]],
                          [0.,          0.,                     0.,      1]])
    return th_matrix


pP = np.array(
    [
     [-0.5, 0, 0, 0.5], # x
     [0, 1, -1, 0],     # y
     [1, 1, 1, 1],      # z
     [1, 1, 1, 1]       # escala
     ])

# translacao
T = np.array([0.6, 0.5, 0])
# rotacao
R_gamma = 45

coP =  H(R_gamma, T, angle = 'deg') @ pP

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (6*2,6))
ax1.plot(pP[0,:], pP[1,:], 'b .', label=r'$\mathbf{{}^oP}$')
ax1.plot(0, 0, 'x')
ax1.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax1.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax1.legend()
ax2.plot(coP[0,:], coP[1,:], 'r .', label=r'$\mathbf{{}^{co}P}$')
ax2.plot(0, 0, 'x')
ax2.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax2.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax2.legend()
```

O resultado pode ser visto pelo gráfico abaixo:

[image: Rotação e Translação Polígono]